# $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y$ . Show that $f'(x)=f'(0)f(x)$ and determine the value of $f'(0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Problem is that Suppose f is differentiable everywhere and $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y$ . Show that $f'(x)=f'(0)f(x)$ and determine the value of $f'(0)$.

I can show $f'(x)=f'(0)f(x)$

but i don't know how to determine the value of $f'(0)$.

Please help!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944229/does-a-function-that-satisfies-the-equality-fab-fafb-have-to-be-expon?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: In the two equations,$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and $f'(x)=f'(0)f(x)$ substitute $x=y=0$.

Comment: @tatan If I do what you say I get first $f(0)=1$ and then $f'(0)=f'(0)$. I don't think that counts as determining the value of $f'(0)$.

Comment: @tatan "substitute $x=y=0$" Right, done, and now what?

Comment: The value of $f'(0)$ is a function of $f(1)$ and it can't be determined unless $f(1)$ is known. It can be proved with some effort that either $f'(0)=0$ (when $f$ is constant) or $f'(0)=\log f(1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to determine the value of $f'(0)$ from the information given -  perhaps you left something out, perhaps the question was stated somewhat differently, or perhaps it's a bad question.

If $a$ is any real number and $f(t)=e^{at}$ then $f$  is differentiable, $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, and $f'(0)=a$. So the information given literally says nothing at all about the value of $f'(0)$; that value can be *anything*.